# Does windows TCP stack sends ACK when the packet is received by the kernel or after the socket read?

Tags: windows, tcp, packet

I understand that in most UNIX based systems, as soon as the kernel receives the packet it sends the ACK. 
But would like to know if the behavior is same in windows operating system too. (Windows 7).

Comment: Normally one would expect the ack to come from the TCP stack and not the client program, unless perhaps an inattentive client had allowed buffers to fill to capacity limits.  But your premise is not necessarily true; the Nagle algorithm can cause a delay in acking isolated packets, irrespective of what application code is doing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't see what 'an inattentive client' has to do with it. Data in the socket receive buffer is acknowledged by TCP, period.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The receive window becomes zero when the receive buffer fills, so the sender stops sending, so the situation you describe cannot possibly arise. This is also what makes the application's reading behaviour irrelevant to ACKs. You seem to be introducing all sorts of extraneous matter into this simple question.

Comment: @user3250651 Unix does not send the ACK 'as soon as the kernel receives the packet'. There are numerous qualifications to that, involving delayed and coalesced ACKs, which mean it can be deferred. But it doesn't have anything to do with when the application reads from the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is the same in all operating systems. It is defined by RFC 793. ACK is performed when (or, in the case of a delayed ACK, after) the data is received by TCP. It has nothing to do with when the application reads.

Comment: This is wrong, because `TCP_NODELAY` among other things allows you to change behavior.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It isn't wrong, and TCP_NODELAY has absolutely nothing to do with it. TCP_NODELAY affects the sender, not the receiver. TCP may choose to delay the ACK, that's all. None of this means that ACK is sent when the application reads, which is what the question is about.

Comment: There is no way it could behave in any other way than by RFC 793 either. If it did, a client could provoke endless resends simply by sending a request to a server and not reading the reply from the socket. If the TCP stack didn't acknowledge, the other end's TCP stack would necessarily have to assume the packet was lost. TCP guarantees delivery, so it would _have to_ resend.

Comment: You are mistaken; delayed/combined acknowledgements are an aspect of TCP efficiency measures as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Mistaken about what? Either TCP sends the ACK when the application reads the data or it doesn't, and it doesn't. 'Efficiency measures' aren't mentioned in the question and don't appear to be relevant to my answer.

Comment: You are mistaken when you say that acks occur when they data is received. Quite often they are delayed to see if an additional packet is received and then both given  a single ack, for efficiency reasons.  That's entirely separate from the question of what happens if more data arrives when the receive buffer is full.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It is you who is mistaken about what I say. Have another look. In any case delayed and coalesced ACKs are irrelevant to the question, as is your so-called 'question of what happens if more data arrives when the receive buffer is full', which I have already addressed in another comment.

Comment: Thing is, a TCP connection has 3 possible conditions (well, a few more, but 3 that matter here). Either it is timed out, which happens only if keepalive is enabled and then only after _an eternity_ (and which a malicious client could trivially postpone forever). Or, the connection is closed or otherwise broken (after FIN/ACK or an ICMP error). Or, lastly, the connection is **alive**. If the connection is alive and there remains unacknowledged data which was accepted by the TCP stack, it has no choice but to resend, resend, and resend. Thus ACK cannot be linked to the client program reading.

Comment: @Damon We're getting off-topic here, but a TCP connection that fails keep-alive gets reset, so it no linger exists at all, so there is nothing to have a state, so it isn't a state of a connection. Similarly CLOSED isn't a state either, it's a pseudo-state, without a connection to be a state of.