# Where are TCP ACKs sent and how to have them sent faster

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, garbage-collection

From answers to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442462) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173153) I learned that the OS/TCP stack is responsible for sending ACKs. In which process does this happen?

Can a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` object that is used for TCP be configured in a way that it sends ACKs as soon as possible, preferably independent of garbage collections?

**Background and Details:**

I have an .NET application that receives data from a device using TCP with a direct network connection from the computer to the device.

The device creates data constantly with about 30 MB/s, and sends them over the network. It uses a buffer to store TCP packets until it receives an ACK. When the buffer overflows, the device stops with an error. Unfortunately, the buffer is only a few kB in size what means that ACKs have to be sent within a few milliseconds.

The device works as it is, I cannot change it, and I have to deal with it.

This worked fine for several years with a relatively simple native program, but with the object oriented and more complicated .NET app, it is not running stable, and I have some suspect that sometimes when the garbage collector runs, ACKs might not be sent quickly enough.

Now there are several things that I could change (e.g. change socket settings, change GC settings, make less allocations, or more drastic things like putting a switch between the device and the computer). My attempts so far have not been successful (except the switch), and this is why I would like to understand what’s going on.

I set `Socket.NoDelay = true`.

**Question:**

Are ACKs being sent within the process of the application or in a different process? If within the process, is this influenced by the .NET garbage collector? What can be done to have ACKs sent faster?

Comment: It happens in the TCP/IP driver stack, not a process.  Neither .NET nor the GC has any direct affect on it.  But TCP does throttle, ACKs are delayed when the kernel buffer fills up to capacity.  So a simple fire-hose problem is an explanation, if the program doesn't call Socket.Read() often enough or sips from the hose with a byte[] that is too small then the device is liable to run into trouble.  Demanding millisecond service time from *any* userland program and not throttling on the device side is almost inevitably going to be a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Is the kernel buffer that what can be set with `ReceiveBufferSize`? If not, is there a way to increase it? (Btw I agree with what you wrote about millisecond service time, but unfortunately I have to make the best of it.)

Comment: Only theoretically, afaik all modern Windows versions ignore it.  Buffer size is never a solution to a fire-hose problem, if the app only can read at a 29 MB/sec rate then no buffer is ever going to be big enough.

Comment: On the otherr hand, even under .net, a dedicated consumer thread (emptying the queue and filling up some secondary buffer) should be able to handle 30MB/s with relative ease I´d assume.

Comment: *"afaik all modern Windows versions ignore it."* - well, he could run it under linux, where you can tweak socket buffer sizes. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @C.Gonzalez True, it can easily handle 300 MB/s, the problem obviously only are short (milliseconds?) pauses, maybe including garbage collector, and with this I think a larger buffer would be helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant The rate is not an issue. Thank you for your hints, it makes sense now.